Is It Advisable to Do Chest Workouts with Sore Legs and Three Consecutive Gym Days?
I did a back workout at the gym yesterday and a leg workout today. I'm certain my legs will be sore tomorrow morning.
Would it be a good idea to do chest exercises like bench presses and chest flies tomorrow, targeting a different muscle group, even if my legs are sore?
This would make it my third consecutive day of gym workouts.
Any alternative ideas like yoga, taichi, swimming, walking etc..that could be better...

How long have you been training?

How do you expect leg muscle soreness to affect a chest workout?

The whole point of a workout split is training one body part while another is recovering. Sorness is just a common side effect of recovery. Make your legs feel fully recovered before the next leg workout but there is no reason to not train other muscle groups in between.
